# Why is an uploaded picture still viewable even if I cancelled my post?

Tags: support, asking-questions, images, uploader

I inserted a picture in one of my Stack Exchange accounts to ask a question, but regretted it and copied the picture's link, then closed the ask question page (I didn't publish it).

When I inserted the copied link in a comment, I saw that, surprisingly, the picture is accessible while I didn't ask the question before!

How did this happen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> How did this happen?

Pictures are uploaded to a special imgur repo (for hosting SE's images) that works independently of any appearance of the image in a post. That's why the uploaded picture will be still accessible.

I even use that as a feature, if I want to post images in a chat room or comments for example:
I am going to an arbitrary post and edit it, upload the image, copy the link and cancel the edit.